# Need help comparing extracted data and outputting to file

Tags: c#

New to C#, and having trouble finding ways to compare data so far collected from conf file, and outputting it to either text or CSV.

I so far have the skeleton of data extraction code from said conf file, however as I'm new to C# and coding overall, I'm having trouble understanding how to reference that data or compare it.

So far have tried File.WriteAllLiness and defining a variable, but not sure which element to parse, or at which point in the code I should introduce it.

Nothing to hide really, so here's the full output so far:

---

```
namespace CompareVal
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\*\*\Cleanup\Script Project\Test-Raw-Conf.txt");
            var ipAddresses = GetIPAddresses(lines);
            var routes = GetRoutes(lines);
            var ipRules = GetIPRules(lines);

            Console.WriteLine ();
        }

        static Dictionary<string, string[]> GetIPAddresses(string[] lines)
        {
            var result = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();

            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                if (!line.StartsWith("add IPAddress"))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                Match match;
                if (line.Contains("Address=\""))
                {
                    match = Regex.Match(line, "add IPAddress (.*?) Address=\"(.*?)\"");
                }
                else
                {
                    match = Regex.Match(line, "add IPAddress (.*?) Address=(.*?)$");
                }

                var name = match.Groups[1].Value;
                var value = match.Groups[2].Value;

                var items = value.Replace(" ", "").Split(',');

                result.Add(name, items);
            }

            return result;

        }

        static List<Route> GetRoutes(string[] lines)
        {
            var result = new List<Route>();

            string currentRoutingTable = null;
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                if (line.StartsWith("cc RoutingTable"))
                {
                    currentRoutingTable = line.Split(' ')[2].Trim();
                }

                if (line == "cc .." && currentRoutingTable != null)
                {
                    currentRoutingTable = null;
                }

                if (line.StartsWith("  add Route"))
                {
                    var @interface = Regex.Match(line, "Interface=(.*?) ").Groups[1].Value;
                    var gateway = Regex.Match(line, "Gateway=(.*?) ").Groups[1].Value;
                    var network = Regex.Match(line, "Network=(.*?) ").Groups[1].Value;

                    result.Add(new Route
                    {
                        RoutingTable = currentRoutingTable,
                        Interface = @interface,
                        Gateway = gateway,
                        Network = network
                    });
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        static List<IPRule> GetIPRules(string[] lines)
        {
            var result = new List<IPRule>();

            string currentIPRuleSet = null;
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                if (line.StartsWith("cc IPRuleSet"))
                {
                    currentIPRuleSet = line.Split(' ')[2].Trim();
                }

                if (line == "cc .." && currentIPRuleSet != null)
                {
                    currentIPRuleSet = null;
                }

                if (line.StartsWith("  add IPRule"))
                {
                    var rule = new IPRule
                    {
                        IPRuleSet = currentIPRuleSet,
                        SourceInterface = GetProperty(line, "SourceInterface"),
                        DestinationInterface = GetProperty(line, "DestinationInterface"),
                    };

                    if (line.Contains("SourceNetwork=\""))
                    {
                        rule.SourceNetwork = GetQuotedProperty(line, "SourceNetwork").Replace(" ", "").Split(',');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rule.SourceNetwork = GetProperty(line, "SourceNetwork").Replace(" ", "").Split(',');
                    }

                    if (line.Contains("DestinationNetwork=\""))
                    {
                        rule.DestinationNetwork = GetQuotedProperty(line, "DestinationNetwork").Replace(" ", "").Split(',');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rule.DestinationNetwork = GetProperty(line, "DestinationNetwork").Replace(" ", "").Split(',');
                    }

                    result.Add(rule);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        static string GetProperty(string input, string propertyName)
        {
            return Regex.Match(input, string.Format("{0}=(.*?) ", propertyName)).Groups[1].Value;
        }

        static string GetQuotedProperty(string input, string propertyName)
        {
            return Regex.Match(input, string.Format("{0}=\"(.*?)\" ", propertyName)).Groups[1].Value;
        }

        class Route
        {
            public string RoutingTable;
            public string Interface;
            public string Gateway;
            public string Network;
        }

        class IPRule
        {
            public string IPRuleSet;
            public string SourceInterface;
            public string DestinationInterface;
            public string[] SourceNetwork;
            public string[] DestinationNetwork;
       }
  }
```

}

I'm hoping to compare values gathered by IPRule, Route and IPAddress classes, and have a method of outputting each associated value in a list.  Each IPAddress is contains a unique string name, but can use any numerical IP address.  The idea is to determine when the same IP has been used multiple times, regardless of IPAddress string name, and then compare this to routes, and flag when they are used in IPRules.

For reference, here are some samples of source data:

For IPAddresses, they can be formed in 1 of 2 ways - as a direct IP definition, or as a reference to another IPAddress object (or multi-reference):
`add IPAddress Test Address=192.168.1.0/24`
IPAddress referencing multiple other IPAddresses:
`add IPAddress TestGroup Address="Test1, Test2, Test3"`

For routes:
`add Route Interface=if5 Gateway=if5_gw Network=Test ProxyARPInterfaces=""`

And for IPRules:
`add IPRule SourceInterface=if5 DestinationInterface=if3 SourceNetwork=Test1 DestinationNetwork=Test2 Service=dns-all Action=Allow`

The above definitions will always follow the same pattern, so the data extraction code has been constructed to expect prefixes to each element, and sort them into their own dictionary or list.

Comment: Could you please post a good sample of the data you're reading?

Comment: From reverse engineering the code I suspect you actually have an IP address and a Mask.   Am I correct?  So you are looking to see the routes based on IP and Mask.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the quick response.  Sure, I'll put some source data here.

Comment: For IPAddresses, they can be formed in 1 of 2 ways - as a direct IP definition, or as a reference to another IPAddress object (or multi-reference).  It looks something like this:  add IPAddress Test Address=192.168.1.0/24

Comment: For routes, it looks like this:   add Route Interface=if5 Gateway=if5_gw Network=Test ProxyARPInterfaces=""

Comment: And for IP Rules, this:  add IPRule SourceInterface=if5 DestinationInterface=if3 SourceNetwork=Test1 DestinationNetwork=Test2 Service=dns-all Action=Allow

Comment: What I can gather so far however, is that the data extraction elements of the code appear to be working as expected.  When I put breakpoints at each return value, I do see expected values contained therein.  The issue I have is in either comparing results from one class to another, or outputting them to a file, as I've mostly relied on a friend to help me construct this code so far, so my understanding is limited.

Comment: @ jdweng - you are mostly correct, there is indeed a CIDR mask as shown above.  The intention is to basically ensure that only one IP/subnet can exist, regardless of name for that IPAddress object.  Also, if a duplicate IP/subnet has been used (same IP, different IPAddress name), then to compare it to Routes and determine if they exist on more than 1 interface.  As a bonus, it would be useful to compare all of that to IP Rules, and flag any IPAddress which is a duplicate of a given subnet.